# How to filter facebook adaccount campaigns with specfic objective in marketing api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am building and Facebook ads manager application. I need to filter the campaigns with specific objectives like "Reach" etc.
I am not able to find any parameter in the Facebook marketing API doc.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns/#Reading

This is the reading example from Facebook.

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/campaigns?effective_status=%5B%22ACTIVE%22%2C%22PAUSED%22%5D&fields=name%2Cobjective',
    '{access-token}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
/* handle the result */
```

is there any parameter that I am missing here? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filtering operator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v9.0), as working example, you could search for all campaigns with `POST_ENGAGEMENT` or `CONVERSIONS` objective in `ACTIVE` or `PAUSED` state:

```
act_xxx/campaigns?fields=name,objective,effective_status&filtering=[{'field':'objective','operator':'IN','value':['POST_ENGAGEMENT','CONVERSIONS']}, {'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ACTIVE','PAUSED']}]
```

will return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": <NAME>,
      "objective": "POST_ENGAGEMENT",
      "effective_status": "PAUSED",
      "id": <ID>
    },
    {
      "name": <NAME>,
      "objective": "CONVERSIONS",
      "effective_status": "PAUSED",
      "id": <ID>
    },
    {
      "name": <NAME>,
      "objective": "POST_ENGAGEMENT",
      "effective_status": "PAUSED",
      "id": <ID>
    },
    {
 
 ....
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!